# solving the bug for java algorthim

Tags: java, algorithm

'the following code is working fine with certain input and not with others
the code is an implementation of a circular linked list 
given a n =length of the list and k= steps to take to delete the node 
the intention is to delete that node that is in the increment of k 
for example if [1,2,3] and k =2 then the first node to be deleted is 2 and then 1 
therefore the last node would be 3
there is 2 test cases on the code the first one is n=12 k=4 and the result should be 1 but i get 2 
at the last elimination step for some reason it get messed up 
the sec test case is n=12 k=3 and the result should be 10 which is working fine
so i  could not figure it out if someone can identify the buy i appreciate it 
thanks'

```
 public static int whoIsElected(int n, int k) {
    LinkedList<Integer> circle = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        circle.add(i);
    }
    int posToDel = k;

    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(posToDel>n)
    {
        posToDel=posToDel%n;
    }
    while(circle.size()>1)
    {
        if(posToDel==0)// becasue the posToDel-1 when posToDel ==0 is the last index
        {
            circle.remove(n-1);
        }
        else
        {
            circle.remove(posToDel-1);
        }
        n--; // decrease the length of n by 1 when u delete one from the list
        // after removing the posToDel in circle

        // this if else set the new posToDel
        if(posToDel==0)
        {
            posToDel=n-1;
        }
        else
        {
            posToDel=posToDel-1;
        }
        if(posToDel+k>n)
        {
            posToDel=(posToDel+k)%n;
        }
        else
        {
            posToDel=posToDel+k;
        }
    }
    return circle.get(0);
}

/**
 * bool doTestsPass()
 * Runs various tests. Returns true if tests pass. Otherwise,
 * returns false.
 */
public static boolean doTestsPass() {
    // todo: implement more tests, please
    // feel free to make testing more elegant
    // test cases are structered as {n, k, expected answer}
    int[][] testCases = {
            {12, 4, 1},// give wrong answer
            {12, 3, 10}// give right answer
    };

    for (int[] testCase : testCases) {
        int answer = whoIsElected(testCase[0], testCase[1]);
        if (answer != testCase[2]) {
            System.out.println("test failed!");
            System.out.printf("n:%d, k%d, answer got: %d, should be: %d\n", testCase[0], testCase[1], answer, testCase[2]);
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("All tested passed");
    return true;
}

/**
 * Execution entry point.
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    doTestsPass();
}
```

}

Comment: I understand you need help to identify the "bug" ... I suggest you may need to take a moment to rephrase your question to get better responses..

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem comes when there are only 3 elements left `[1,2,9]`

So, when trying it manually, it comes out that the *posToDel* should be `3` when element 9 is going to be deleted, but when we run that in code, *posToDel* value is `0`.

You can try adding console logs and tracking values at different points of time. But it can become messy quickly and you might end up spending more time than required.

However, I can suggest you to try below algorithm in the loop logic:

Before loop assign `posToDel= k-1`, so that you won't have to do posToDel-1 in loop each time (just makes building different logics in loop little bit easy with less special cases)

I have tried below logic in loop, it works fine for your test cases:

```
while( circle.size() > 1 )
        {
            int temp = circle.remove( posToDel );
            System.out.println( temp );
            n--;
            posToDel = posToDel - 1;
            System.out.println( "after deletion of " + temp + ", pos is: " + posToDel );
            if( posToDel + k >= n )
            {
                posToDel = ( posToDel + k ) % n;
            }
            else
            {
                posToDel = posToDel + k;
            }
        }
```

Have added 2 sysout statements to know the order of deletion, which might help in debugging

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one for looking at this 
i figured it out 
here is the right code

```
public class WhoIsElected {

public static int whoIsElected(int n, int k) {

    /*******************************************start solution*******************************/
    LinkedList<Integer> circle = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        circle.add(i);
    }
    int posToDel = k;

    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(posToDel>n)
    {
        posToDel=posToDel%n;
    }
    while(circle.size()>1)
    {
        if(posToDel==0)// becasue the posToDel-1 when posToDel ==0 is the last index
        {
            circle.remove(n-1);
        }
        else
        {
            circle.remove(posToDel-1);
        }
        n--; // decrease the length of n by 1 when u delete one from the list
        // after removing the posToDel in circle

        if(posToDel>0)
        {
            posToDel=posToDel-1;
        }
        if(posToDel+k>n)
        {
            posToDel=(posToDel+k)%n;
        }
        else
        {
            posToDel=posToDel+k;
        }
    }
    return circle.get(0);
    /*******************************************end solution*******************************/
}


/**
 * bool doTestsPass()
 * Runs various tests. Returns true if tests pass. Otherwise,
 * returns false.
 */
public static boolean doTestsPass() {
    // todo: implement more tests, please
    // feel free to make testing more elegant
    // test cases are structered as {n, k, expected answer}
    int[][] testCases = {
            {1, 1, 1},
            {2, 2, 1},
            {2, 5, 2},// my add test to have k bigger than n
            {100, 2, 73},
            {4,2,1},
            {5, 3, 4},
            {6, 4, 5},
            {12, 4, 1},
            {12, 3, 10},
            {1000,5,763}
    };

    for (int[] testCase : testCases) {
        int answer = whoIsElected(testCase[0], testCase[1]);
        if (answer != testCase[2]) {
            System.out.println("test failed!");
            System.out.printf("n:%d, k%d, answer got: %d, should be: %d\n", testCase[0], testCase[1], answer, testCase[2]);
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("All tested passed");
    return true;
}

/**
 * Execution entry point.
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    doTestsPass();
}
class Node {

}
```

}

Comment: Could tell us, briefly, what the code does that is different from the code posted in the question?

Comment: @Momo my point was if you assign value of (k-1) to posToDel, you won't need special conditions like when (pos==0) in your while loop, since it'll be automatically taken care of, it's just a simple algo then,->delete at pos->size=size-1->pos=pos-1->count kth position from current pos->continue to next iteration, I just tried all the test cases with the code I have given in my answer, it passed for all